# Changing the order of arrays to match a master array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays gathered from a form $_POST including an SKU, plug and voltage

The SKU features a model number at the start and a colour identifier at the end - these have to be in alphabetical order of colour.

to compensate for information being entered out of order I'm doing the following:

from

```
[modelsku] => Array([0] => RCS22334WW [1] => RCS22334SS  )

foreach($_POST["modelsku"] as $modelsku){
    $newSKUarray[] = strrev($modelsku);
}
sort($newModelSKUarray)
```

So now the models are in order - I simply strrev($modelsku) when echoing them later.

My problem is that the accompanying arrays are not in the same order - is there a way to have other arrays sorted the same way as the sky array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `array_multisort()`? You can also use `array_map()` instead of your foreach loop.

```
<?
$skus = array('RCS22334WW', 'RCS22334SS');
$plugs = array('bigPlug', 'smallPlug');
$voltages = array('10', '20');

$skus_backwards = array_map('strrev', $skus);
array_multisort($skus_backwards, $skus, $plugs, $voltages);

var_dump($skus);
var_dump($plugs);
var_dump($voltages);
?>
```

Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "RCS22334SS" [1]=> string(10) "RCS22334WW" } array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "smallPlug" [1]=> string(7) "bigPlug" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(2) "10" }
```

Comment: Perfect - I thought the answer lay in array mapping or multi sort but arrays always give me a headache